# Changing meta-tags dynamic with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

These are my meta-tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="assets/css/gfx/skold.png"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Den historie hjemmesiden for Norges Golfforbund"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Her finner du alle de historie tingene som har skjedd i Norges golfhistorie gjennom tidene" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://###"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Norges Golfklubb"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="sport"/>
```

And I am trying to change them dynamic with the following code:

```
$("meta[property=og:title]").attr("content", result.title);
```

But I am keep getting Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [property=og:title] in Firebug.

Using the latest version of jQuery. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If this is for Facebook to scrape, keep in mind that if you update them with JavaScript, Facebook won't have access to the modified value.

Comment: Well. They have default values, but the webpage is made up by Ajax and Javascript entierly, so I have to change the information in other to share the right content to Facebook.

Comment: You need a default value for a permalink, can't have a dynamicly generated OG tag for facebook, it will always return default or empty then when you try to link it in a FB comment/share box.

Comment: Is there ANYWAY to get this to work?  I see people saying that they can make it work on a php page but I have an html page that grabs the ?id=whatever and goes to town with JQuery and ajax.  Is there any order I can call this in for facebook to recognize these new values?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think you should escape `:` look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
No need of ":".

```js
$("meta[property='og\\title']").attr("content", result.title);
```

Comment: you can put it in single quotes too.

Comment: `'og:title'` should be in single quotes

Comment: @Relic it works anyway, in any case i changed to use single quotes

Comment: note that if you are checking if this is working you should inspect the DOM since view source will not reflect the change.

Comment: @GayanDasanayake Is there anyway, It can be changed on source too. Because when I share page on fb, it takes old og:image, not new updated.

Comment: @user3288891 The facebook crawler does not execute javascript. So it will not get updated meta property. You have to use server code to update it.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("meta[name='og:title']").attr('content', 'my new title');
```

Using "property=" does not work in Chrome

Answer (score 5):

You could give each meta element an ID or Class.

```
$('#metaelement').attr('content', 'my new meta description');
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your quotes are like this:

```
$('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content',"$modified_desc" );
```

Comment: This would be proper to what you're trying to accomplish even though the end result will still be the same so you solve the symptom not the issue.