# dynamically change metadata - no jquery

Tags: javascript

[I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308970/changing-meta-tags-dynamic-with-jquery) on changing meta data using jQuery `$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", result.title);`, 
 
but is it possible to do it with straight javascript?

I know you can access an items attribute like so `document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src","another.gif")`, 
but i cant seem to change metadata.

I am trying to dynamically alter metadata for facebook.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="*************" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Comment: Is this the first item in the `meta` list?

Comment: JQuery is written in javascript so it is possible. The real question is how much effort you want to put forth.

Comment: @tymeJV im sorry i think i misread your question,  what did you mean?

Comment: In your list of meta tags, is the facebook meta tag always first? If so, I think you can do something like `var metaFB = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];`

Comment: Are you having problems getting a reference to the element or with `setAttribute`?

Comment: @tymeJV  thank you,  if you put that as an answer i will accept it

Comment: @FelixKling i couldnt target metatags,  did not know about `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the `meta` tag you want to modify is first in the list, you can do:

```
var metaFB = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];
```

Now you can modify the attributes to your liking.

Edit: As @Jamiec points out, even if it's not first in the list, you can specify where. If you don't know where, you can iterate through the elements check the attributes:

```
var metaList = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
for (var i = 0; i < metaList.length; i++) {
    if (metaList[i].getAttribute("property") == "fb:app_id") {
        metaList[i].content = "somenewcontent";
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, if it's *not* first in the list you could just use a different number. Or if you dont know where in the list it was you could enumerate looking at the `property` attribute.