# Does Facebook Sharer.php parameter's alternative method avaiable?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={URL}&p[title]={TITLE}&p[summary]={SUMMARY}
```

Facebook have stopped above method.

> What is the alternative method for sharing all data like this?

**Pls note :**
I want to share multiple summary on single url. So og tags will not help for multiple content sharing on single url.

Comment: That is not possible. You have to have unique urls for each content

Comment: Don't have any alternative way to share ?

Comment: Not possible means that there are no alternatives. If there was alternatives it would be possible

Comment: Might be help to other : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308970/changing-meta-tags-dynamic-with-jquery

Comment: Which will not work because Facebook don't execute Javascript