# Dynamic social meta tags in url

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

So here is the challenge that I have.

I have a bunch of back-end controllers which get the request and generate some responses.
I know the front-end people can use those responses and generate the required social meta tags dynamically. For example they can produce the following snippet in their template's :

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="" >
    <meta property="og:description" content="" >
    <meta property="og:image" content="" >
```

But my question is, is there anyway that I can send the social tags via URL. 
In other words I don't want to have a template with some placeholders for social tags. I just want to generate them on the fly when a specific URL was requested and passing them via the URL.

Something like: http://example.com/api/action?og:image=someimage.png

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to reiterate that I am almost positive that your problem is due to the fact that the url you are passing into the debugger is not dynamically generated. The url tag essentially acts as a redirector. Unless it's the exact same (meaning the meta tags on the url meta object is the same as those on the url you are passing in) as the url you are testing, you won't get the results you're looking for.

The meta tag

```
<meta property="og:url">
```

needs to be dynamically generated. The debugger is being redirected to your default index page instead of the dynamically generated page.

For example, I assign an id to every object I'm using, and so I have something like the following

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://Example.com/index.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
```

I pass in that exact url into the debugger, and thus the final page the debugger lands on will be that exact url.

Also, in the following

```
<meta property="og:type" content=""/>
```

how is the property being dynamically generated? Did you remember to set in your actual code something like the following?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo _GET['type] ?>"/>
```

You also appear to be shoving everything into the url, which is dangerous and can cause huge headaches, which might be the issue here. Instead, shove only one thing , eg ?type=bistro and then propagate the necessary data from the DB.

I would recommend dynamically generating most OG tags based on an object_id. Store the relevant OG info for every object_id, and then propagate them when accessed. This way, you can also easily expand and edit the tags you use when OG is updated.

If you have problems with OG you shouldn't hesitate to post them as new questions instead of comments as I guarantee other people also have the same problem.

[Refer This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308970/changing-meta-tags-dynamic-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ivin. But my question is not about adding dynamic content to a meta tag. My question is how to generate the whole <meta> tag line. Like I said imagine I have a template which doesn't have meta tags place holders. In other words I can not pass values to the content attribute in the <meta>. Is there any other ways which I can generate the meta tags and pass them via HTTP responses? If yes what the response string should look like? Thank you.