# How to update meta tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, meta

I am aware that this question comes up a lot, but I haven't been able to solve my problem yet.

I have a website driven by php that contains videos. The different videos have their own URL, like *index.php?id=1*. For facebook sharing I want each video/URL to have updated meta tags.

The information for each video (Title, description, etc.) is stored in a database, and I am successfully retreiving that information to my site.

Here is the script that passes a variable from javascript to PHP:

```
<script>
        var video;
        var URL = document.location;

        function setVideo(src){
            video = src;

            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: URL,
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: { 
                            videoPHP: video,      
                            }, 
                        success: function(data) {
                            // This prints the php result to html
                            $('#headerFromFile').html(data)
                         }
                     });
             });
         }
</script>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['videoPHP'])) {

    $videoID = $_GET['videoPHP'];

    // SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE ID='$videoID'";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $row['Header'];?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $row['Description'];?></p>
<?php
```

By doing this I am able to echo the Header and the Description for the video to the div *#headerFromFile* in my html document.

The problem, however, is that I would like to have this information stored to the **meta property="og:title"** and **meta property="og:description"** of the current URL.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing meta-tags dynamic with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308970/changing-meta-tags-dynamic-with-jquery)

Comment: Your _server_ needs to return the HTML document with the correct meta data, when `index.php?id=1` is requested. You can not set OG meta tags using client-side code, the Facebook scraper does not care about that. You basically want to scrap the AJAX part here completely, and move the PHP code into the `head`, and make it output metatags there.

Comment: Fantastic. That did the trick. I got rid of the ajax, and moved the php section into the head section of the html. From there I could echo the php variables directly into the meta tags. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag is written to the dom before your ajax runs. I suggest you get the data bout of the DB before the page loads and put variables in your meta tag.

However, if I understand correctly, your content may change after the dom is loaded and when posting to facebook the old meta data is read. I don;t know if this will help because Facebook might not get the updated meta tag either but try ot change the meta tage like so...

```
 $('meta[name=description]').remove();
 $('head').append( "<meta name='description' content='Video Title'>" );
```

Comment: facebook does not run javascript, so changing the metatags with javascript is pointless.