# Remove and append viewport using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I came across a HTML page having the following piece of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var screen_width = parseInt(jQuery(window).innerWidth());
    var scale = screen_width / 1200;
    $('head').remove('<meta name="viewport">');
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi,width=device-width,initial-scale=' + scale.toFixed(1) + ',minimum-scale=0.1,user-scalable=yes"/>');
});
```

When I inspect the webpage, the following error appears under Console:

> jquery.js:13 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   `<meta name="viewport">`
>       at Function.ga.error (jquery.js:13)
>       at ga.tokenize (jquery.js:16)
>       at ga.compile (jquery.js:20)
>       at ga.select (jquery.js:20)
>       at ga (jquery.js:10)
>       at Function.ga.matchesSelector (jquery.js:13)
>       at Function.r.filter (jquery.js:20)
>       at Ka (jquery.js:34)
>       at r.fn.init.remove (jquery.js:35)
>       at HTMLDocument. (review:1878)

The error disappeared if `$('head').remove('<meta name="viewport">');`is being commented out. Is this the correct way of removing the viewport?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing meta-tags dynamic with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308970/changing-meta-tags-dynamic-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute and value selector to remove element:

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that:

Option 1:

```
$('head meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
```

Option 2:

```
$('head').find('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
```

Option 3:

```
$('head meta[name="viewport"]').prop('outerHTML', '<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi,width=device-width,initial-scale=' + scale.toFixed(1) + ',minimum-scale=0.1,user-scalable=yes"/>');
```

Note: With option 3, you don't need to *remove* that element.

Answer (score 0):

It caused an error because of the wrong implementation of "remove function". When you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

When you specify an element for .remove() be sure to use selectors which are element names, id, classes, etc.

The code must be like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var screen_width = parseInt(jQuery(window).innerWidth());
   var scale = screen_width / 1200;
   $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
   $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device dpi,width=device-width,initial-scale=' + scale.toFixed(1) + ',minimum-scale=0.1,user-scalable=yes"/>');
});
```

Or much better implementation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var screen_width = parseInt(jQuery(window).innerWidth());
   var scale = screen_width / 1200;
   $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', "target-densitydpi=device dpi,width=device-width,initial-scale=' + scale.toFixed(1) + ',minimum-scale=0.1,user-scalable=yes'/>");
});
```